# TimeOut Linq Alter Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

How do I alter the TimeOut of Linq in my WebConfig file?

Is possible?

In code-behind I can write:

```
db.CommandTimeout = 3600;
```

Can this be done based on a WebConfig entry?

Comment: in Web.Config setup settings section then read the settings value inside the Code Behind

Comment: what is the name of tag in webconfig? to i alter!!!! unknow the name of tag!!! help me!

Comment: The Framework should support a declarative setting for Command Timeout or support it in the connection string. (We have code that we don't directly support timing-out...)

Answer (score 2):

1. Right Click your Project and go to Properties
2. On left hand side click Settings
3. Click the link to create a settings file
4. In The Name Type DBTimeout
5. In the Type set to int
6. In the Scope set to Application
7. In the value set to 3600 (or any other value)

Save this and then go to your code behind and add the following:

```
db.CommandTimeout = Properties.Settings.Default.DBTimeOut;
```

This will then allow you to edit the DBTimeout Value via the Web.config typically at the bottom under Application Settings. This should get you what you want. Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: tank you, more it seems is self thing of i put in an <add key="">, dont´t have other away, even more

Comment: go accept your answer yes, i my exemple what want would equal of session timeout where you set in webconfig, more your answer this correct!